# SQL Server replace all values before a colon and after a semi-colon

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring

I have a column say `Test`.

The test have values like `asp:test;abca`, `asps:tesst;abcsa`, `asssp:tsest;assbca`

I am only interested in the text before a `;` and after `:`, so my result should be like

```
test, tesst, tsest
```

I just want to do it with a SQL query and not programatically in code.

Does SQL Server support some sort of regex?

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

The most **important** part is that some values may not have `;` and `:` so my query should also not fail might be some sort of check for this

Comment: What results would you expect if the data does not contain a colon and/or semi-colon?

Comment: I strongly recommend not to do anything in database except crud. Database is for **storing** data not for **processing**! Process it in app side. If `asp` and `test` and `abca` carry some meaning then split them into three columns. Normalize it!!!

Comment: @GMastros I am really sorry for the late reply i want to get the complete string if there is no colon and semi-colon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
declare @T table
(
  Col varchar(20)
)

insert into @T values
('asp:test;abca'), 
('asps:tesst;abcsa'), 
('asssp:tsest;assbca'),
('asssp:tsestassbca'),
('asssptsest;assbca'),
('asssptsestassbca'),
(':;')

select  left(T2.Col, charindex(';', T2.Col+';')-1) 
from @T as T1
  cross apply (select stuff(T1.Col, 1, charindex(':', T1.Col), '')) as T2(Col)
```

Comment: WOW! That looks like black magic and voodoo combined - but it works! :-)

Comment: @MikaelEriksson You are genius even after working for the next 10 years i cannot write such a query. You are gr88888888888888.

Answer (score 4):

For sql engine supported string functions: substring, charindex:

```
SUBSTRING(s, CHARINDEX(':', s) + 1, CHARINDEX(';', s) - CHARINDEX(':', s) - 1)
```

Full code with error processing

```
case 
  when CHARINDEX(':', s) > 0 and CHARINDEX(';', s) > 0 
    then SUBSTRING(s, CHARINDEX(':', s) + 1, CHARINDEX(';', s) - CHARINDEX(':', s) - 1) 
 else null
end
```

Comment: This code will fail if the data does not contain a colon or semi-colon.

Comment: See my reply for a simpler way to handle this.

Answer (score 3):

T-SQL does have PATINDEX to do pattern matching, but does not support a robust regex API. However, if you have SQL Server 2005 and later, you could create a [CLR user-defined function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx). However, you may be able to accomplish what you want with a regular user-defined function using PATINDEX/CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an sample using CharIndex that does what you want and does not fail if the colon or semi-colon are missing.

```
Declare @Temp Table(Test VarChar(50))

Insert Into @Temp Values('asp:test;abca')
Insert Into @Temp Values('asps:tesst;abcsa')
Insert Into @Temp Values('asssp:tsest;assbca')
Insert Into @Temp Values('Hello World')
Insert Into @Temp Values('Hello World:')
Insert Into @Temp Values('Hello World;')

Select  SubString(Test, CharIndex(':', Test) + 1, CharIndex(';', Test + ':;') - CharIndex(':', Test) - 1)
From    @Temp
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write a function like this that would handle all cases - there is a colon (`:`) and/or there is a semicolon (`;`) - or none at all. In any case, this would return the string fragment you're looking for:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.ExtractString (@InputString VARCHAR(500))
RETURNS VARCHAR(500)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(500)

    DECLARE @ColonPos INT, @SemicolonPos INT

    SET @ColonPos = CHARINDEX(':', @InputString)
    SET @SemicolonPos = CHARINDEX(';', @InputString)

    IF @ColonPos > 0 
        IF @SemicolonPos > 0
            SET @Result = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @ColonPos + 1, @SemicolonPos - 1 - @ColonPos)
        ELSE    
            SET @Result = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @ColonPos + 1, 500)
    ELSE
        IF @SemicolonPos > 0
            SET @Result = SUBSTRING(@InputString, 1, @SemicolonPos - 1)
        ELSE    
            SET @Result = @InputString

    RETURN @Result
END
```

Since it's just a string manipulation function, it shouldn't be too bad in terms of performance, either.

If you run it against various inputs:

```
SELECT 
    dbo.ExtractString('asp:test;abca'),
    dbo.ExtractString('asps:tesst;abcsa'), 
    dbo.ExtractString('asssp:tsest;assbca'),
    dbo.ExtractString('test'),
    dbo.ExtractString('a:test'),
    dbo.ExtractString('atest;something')
```

you get these results:

```
test   tesst   tsest   test   test   atest
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
DECLARE @n TABLE (test VARCHAR(100))

INSERT @n (test)
VALUES  ('asp:test;abca'), ('asps:tesst;abcsa'), ('asssp:tsest;assbca')

INSERT @n (test)
VALUES  ('asptest;abca'), ('asps:tesstabcsa'), ('asssptsestassbca')


SELECT SUBSTRING(test, CHARINDEX(':', test) + 1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(';', test), 0), LEN(test) + 1) - CHARINDEX(':', test) - 1)
FROM @n
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but please read my updated questions some values may not have : and/or ; so in this case the query must not fail

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Thanks for advise, I will. Just still not familiar with editor tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a substring or patindex as suggested by others (My personal preference would be for a UDF).

However, you need to be aware that using these techniques as part of the WHERE clause will likely cause a table scan.

Depending on the size of your data, server load, and frequency of making this query, it may make more sense to try something else. For instance, adding another column with this data populated.